# Submitting a Textbox form with enter button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a text box that I would like the user to input a string into, and then when the user hits the "enter" key it create an option in a select box with the option equaling the text that was in the text box

I have this functionality working with a "submit" button but I would like to remove this button and have it so when the user hits "enter" the functionality would work. My question is how would I change my code to allow this functionality?

Comment: What code have you tried? I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id='myform' >
<input type="textbox" id="field"/>
</form>


$(function(){
   $("#field").keyup(function(event){
   if(event.which == 13){
   document.myform.submit();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to detect the enter key like this:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    // Do whatever the submit button does now
  }
});
```

However, the enter key usually brings you to a new line in a text box. That would no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#textBox').keypress(function(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {  // detect the enter key
        $('#btnSubmit').click(); // This will call a click event of submit button
    }
});

$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e) {
    // Write your code to insert text value to select option
});

});
```